# Ionic 2 release app can not open connection to DB

Tags: ionic2

Recently, I have developed an app using Ionic 2, the app creates Sqlite DB and feed it using web API. Everything working great through IonicView and unsigned .apk app version. But the release version of the app does NOT able to open a connection to DB, I have checked the whole functions of this version, everything working as in the unsigned version except opening the DB.

Any Ideas. Thanks